# How can insert list items to database in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is my template :

```
{% for pr in productlist %}

<ul>
  <li>{{ pr.productid }} <input type="hidden" id="prid" name="mylist" value="{{ pr.productid }} "></li>
  <li>{{ pr.productname }} <input type="hidden" id="prname" name="mylist" value="{{ pr.productname }}"></li>
  <li><input type="number" name="mylist" id="prqty"/></li>
</ul>

{% endfor %}
```

I get list of items in view : `pd = request.POST.getlist("mylist")` and result is:

```
 1
 product1
 23

 2
 product2
 44

 3
 product3
 18
```

and complete view is this :

```
def post(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        
        pd = request.POST.getlist("mylist")  
        
        #invoice
        invoice = models.Sellinvoice.objects.create(                    
                type = "5",
                date = datetime.datetime.now()
                )
        
        #invoiceItems
        for item in pd:
                qty = 1
                models.Sellinvoiceitems (
                                productid = <<-- problem,
                                productname = <<-- problem,
                                totalnumber = <<-- problem,
                                sellinvoice = invoice,
                                stockid = stock
                            ).save()

                invoice.save()
```

**My question is how i save all item in above list using for each?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate over chunks of three with:

```
pd = request.POST.getlist('mylist') 
pdi = iter(pd)
for pid, pname, ptotal, __ in zip(pdi, pdi, pdi, pdi):
    models.Sellinvoiceitems.objects.create(
        productid=pid
        productname=pname,
        totalnumber=ptotal,
        sellinvoice = invoice,
        stockid = stock
    )
```

That being said, I would advise *not* to process `POST` parameters yourself. You can work with a [**`FormSet`** for that [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: Thank for your help now i trying, my problem with formset is i dont know how to fill formset with mylist

Comment: @hami: you can make a `ModelFormSet` by defining a `ModelForm`, and then turn it into a `ModelFormSet` with the `modelformset_factory`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/models/#modelformset-factory Then you can pass the data with a `queryset=...` parameter when you construct the `ModelFormSet`.

Comment: @hami: did you use `.objects.create(...)`? Can you see that it is enumerating over the chunks (for example by using a `print` statement)?

Comment: @hami: ah, but there are apparently for items with the name `mylist`. Then you should use the iterator four times.

Comment: Yessss, You saved me thanks. i buy a coffee for you.

Comment: can you please check my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627844/how-to-insert-selected-items-to-db-in-django