# How to insert selected items to db in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Here is my Template :

```
{% for pr in productlist %}

<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="mylistch" value="{{ pr.productid }}"></li>
  <li><input type="hidden" name="mylist" value="{{ pr.productname }}"></li>
  <li><input type="number" name="mylist" id="prqty"/></li>
</ul>

{% endfor %}
```

and View :

```
pch = request.POST.getlist('mylistch') 
pnch = iter(pch)

pr = request.POST.getlist('mylist')
pri = iter(pr)

for pid, pname, ptotal in zip(pnch , pri , pri):
    models.Sellinvoiceitems.objects.create(
        productid=pid
        productname=pname,
        totalnumber=ptotal,
        sellinvoice = invoice,
        stockid = stock
    )
```

Here i checked 5 checkbox with this ids : 6 , 9 , 10 , 12 , 19, But ids : 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 inserted to db, what is problem here?

Comment: I would really advise to work with `FormSet`s: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/ This makes handling the data less error prone and more effective.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem see in this time really i can not using formsets, it is my program in next. what you think about this question?

Comment: Well with the current implementation, it is not possible, for the simple reason that a HTML form only submits the values of the checkboxes that are checked, so that means `mylistch` will not (per se) contain the same amount of elements as the `mylist`.

Comment: A `FormSet` handles that by prefixing each checkbox. This is a robust way to handle data, and thus is a both a safer and more effective way.

Comment: You mean in ```formset``` i can using existing lists? also using inputs in same rows?